# How to Get values From Sub Model in asp.net Core2.2 using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using Ajax in my Asp.net core 2.2 which works just fine but I'm stack with the Json value which returns `undefined` since in the View I'm using a different way to post the Data in the page.

**How can ajax `GET` the correct data when My View looks like:**

```
<div class="treeview">
                        @{
                            if (Model._InstanceDepartment != null && Model._InstanceDepartment.Count() > 0)
                            {

                                <ul>
                                    @foreach (var i in Model._InstanceDepartment)
                                    {
                                        <li>
                                            <span class="collapse collapsible" data-loaded="false" pid="@i.DepartId">&nbsp;</span>
                                            <span>
                                                <a href="#@i.NavUrl" onclick="mydevpartmanifested()">@i.DepatName</a>

                                            </span>                                           
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
```

**And Ajax Get the Data from Controller Like**

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/User/SubMenu",
                type: "GET",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (d) {
                    $(this1).removeClass("loadingP");

                    if (d.length > 0) {

                        var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                        $.each(d, function (i, ele) {
                            $ul.append(
                                $("<li></li>").append(
                                    "<span class='collapse collapsible' data-loaded='false' pid='" + ele.DepartId + "'>&nbsp;</span>" +
                                    "<span><a href='" + ele.NavUrl + "'>" + ele.DepatName + "</a></span>"
                                )
                            )
                        });

                        $(this1).parent().append($ul);
                        $(this1).addClass('collapse');
                        $(this1).toggleClass('collapse expand');
                        $(this1).closest('li').children('ul').slideDown();
                    }
else{...} ../code continue just fine.
```

The problem is that I'm no getting the life of data from `Model` But from `Model.__InstanceDepartment`

VS2019 DEBUG show like:

[image]

**The controller looks like this:**

```
  public JsonResult SubMenu(string pid) 
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var subcomp = new UserSecurityMains();
            int pID = 0;
            int.TryParse(pid, out pID);
            using (QAEntities context = new QAEntities())
            {
                subcomp._InstanceDepartment = context.AuthDepartment.Where(x => x.ParentMenuId.Equals(pID)).OrderBy(c => c.DepatName).ToList();
            }
            return Json(subcomp._InstanceDepartment); 
        }
```

> What I need is that the data which is found under
>   `_InstanceDepartment` as shown on the picture, must be accessible in
>   `if(d.length > 0)` to display the data. Currently, it's displays none,
>   `undefined`

**Anyone Has a Fast/Quick way to do this??**

Comment: You question isnt very clear. However I assume you just need to use `d._InstanceDepartment` instead if `d` in your  `$.each...`

Comment: @JamesP I have just updated the question. However, I have tried to use `d._InstanceDepartment` did not work at all, display run-time error.  I'm sure that it's has something to do with how I call the data from my controller!

Comment: Can you provide code for controller action & for a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JamesP please check the question details. I have added the Controller so long. however, If you think you may have an idea of the answer, please provide some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of things wrong. Firstly you need to remember [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) uses an index. Also the default Serializer used for json will use camelCase by default, unless you change it in `ConfigureServices`.

Something like the following should get it working:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/User/SubMenu",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $(this1).removeClass("loadingP");

                //You can view what it returned in the browser console
                //console.log(data);

                if (data.length > 0) {

                    var $ul = $("<ul></ul>");

                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {

                        $ul.append(
                            $("<li></li>").append(
                                "<span class='collapse collapsible' data-loaded='false' pid='" + data[index].departId + "'>&nbsp;</span>" +
                                "<span><a href='" + data[index].navUrl + "'>" + data[index].depatName + "</a></span>"
                            )
                        )
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about it! Your approach is more clear than what I though. I Have a simple question which will be a MasterPiece. Still with the above source codes,  I'm building a TreeView from the following link:  `http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2014/06/how-to-populate-treeview-nodes-dynamic-ondemand-mvc4.html` ; However in the JS they make use of: `$(".collapsible").live("click", function (e)` which works fine with Jquery 1.7.1  which is old, How can I implement with the same JS code using Jquery 3.3.1?

Comment: In the comments someone recommends using `$(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function (e) { ` instead

Comment: OMG I spent hours to get it right! I add to use `$(document).on('click', '.collapsible', function (e) {` on the same line. Now I can make use of JQery Database + TreeView on the same page!!! Brilliant!!! You are a day savior. Thank you very much :) :_